# Java SimpleDateFormat Pattern for JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I need to convert a Java Date object to a string that is the same format as JavaScript Dates when they are converted to a string. On our server we have JavaScript dates that are `.toString()`'d and have a format like:

`Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

And I have a Java Date object that I am trying to convert to a string of the same format. So far my `SimpleDateFormat` pattern is

`EEE MMM dd yyyy '00:00:00'` (The hours, minutes and secs will always be 0) but I can't figure out the proper pattern for the time zone (`GMT-0400 (EDT)`)

Thanks for the help! Here is the Java code I'm using so far in case it helps:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy '00:00:00'");
Date date = arrayOfDates[i];
String dateStr = format.format(date);
// Current dateStr = "Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00"
```

**EDIT**

Vaibhav Jain's answer put me on the right track ([Java SimpleDateFormat Pattern for JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752632/java-simpledateformat-pattern-for-javascript-date/35753048#35752915))

The final format I ended up using is:

`EEE MMM dd yyyy '00:00:00' 'GMT'Z '('z')'`

Thanks again, all!

Comment: just to clarify `arrayOfDates[i]` has dates in the format of `Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` or is it in milliseconds?

Comment: @depperm ```arrayOfDates``` is of type ```java.util.Date[]``` and holds dates that need to be parsed into strings with the format ```Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)``` (obviously not this exact date, it would be whatever the date of the ```arrayOfDates[i]``` is. Hope that helps clarify things.

Comment: Note that in javascript (actually ECMAScript), [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) is **entirely** implementation dependent, so while there might be some commonality between implementations, there is no certainty of conformance to any particular format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy '00:00:00'  zZ");
Date date = arrayOfDates[i];
String dateStr = format.format(date);
```

Comment: This was very close and put me on the right track! The format that worked was ```EEE MMM dd yyyy '00:00:00' zZ '('z')'``` the answer really helped me figure it out, so I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

Parsing string.

```
ZonedDateTime.parse ( 
    "Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)" ).withLocale ( Locale.US ) 
)
```

Generating string.

```
myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()
              .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )
              .format( 
                  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)" )
                                   .withLocale ( Locale.US ) 
              )
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### Parsing strings

Define a formatting pattern with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

The modern pattern codes are similar to the legacy `SimpleDateFormat` codes, but **not exactly identical**. Study the documentation. The subtleties of the zone/offset pattern codes eludes me, but some trial-and-error found a combination that seems to work. Test thoroughly, as I have not; use at your own risk.

```
String input = "Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"; // EDT
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'x (z)" ).withLocale ( Locale.US );

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , f );
```

Generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2016-03-30T00:00-04:00[America/New_York]

By the way, if at all possible I suggest you use the standard ISO 8601 formats rather than the format shown in your Question. Much easier to parse and easier to read by humans across cultures.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. **Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation** such as `EST` or `EDT` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

### Generating strings

Convert any `java.util.Date` to its modern equivalent, `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

To convert, look to new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Adjust into the desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Generate a string using the same `DateTimeFormatter` object seen above.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'x (z)" ).withLocale ( Locale.US );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

### Live code

See this example [code live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/RQ6wu5).

```
String input = "Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"; // EDT
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)" ).withLocale ( Locale.US );

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , f );

String output = zdt.format ( f );

System.out.println ( "input: " + input );
System.out.println ( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt );
System.out.println ( "output: " + output );
System.out.println ( "input equals output: " + input.equals ( output ) );
```

> input: Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
>
> zdt.toString(): 2016-03-30T00:00-04:00[America/New_York]
>
> output: Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
>
> input equals output: true

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

To format the date exactly like that, we may need to format date and timezone separately, e,g,:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String dateStr = format.format(date);
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
int offset = tz.getRawOffset();

String text = String.format("%s%02d%02d", offset >= 0 ? "+" : "-", offset / 3600000, (offset / 60000) % 60);

String timeZoneText = "GMT" + text + " (" + tz.getDisplayName(true, tz.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())+")";

System.out.println(dateStr + " " + timeZoneText);
```

Answer (score -1):

Typically if a given date is valid then the date object created should return back the same date, month and year value. Below logic worked for most of the cases that I coded.

**Example:** 29-Feb-2018 does not exist, but when javascript accepts this input as Date("2018-02-29") it creates a date value of 1-Mar-2018.

**Javascript Function:**

```
    function dateCheck(dd,mm,yyyy)
    {
      var tempDt = new Date(parseInt(yyyy), parseInt(mm)-1, parseInt(dd), 0, 0, 0, 0);

      if(tempDt.getDate()!=parseInt(dd) ||
        tempDt.getFullYear()!=parseInt(yyyy) ||
        tempDt.getMonth() + 1 !=parseInt(mm))
        return false;
      else
        return true;
    }
```