# Date/Time format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have a time string which is `01:00:00` all I want to do is convert it to `1:00 am` using Javascript date time conversion.

I have tried `SimpleDateFormat` which gives `SimpleDateFormat is not defined`

Following are the links i found but could not understand or implement:

1. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768606/i-have-a-utc-string-and-i-want-to-convert-it-to-utc-date-object-in-javascript/40768745#40768745) gives `Invalid Date`
2. [This](https://github.com/noahcooper/SimpleDateFormatJS) gives `SimpleDateFormat is not defined`
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752632/java-simpledateformat-pattern-for-javascript-date) gives the same.

I just want to understand how date and time formatting works in Javascript.

I already do it in java with `SimpleDateFormat`, but i think it is not as easy in JS.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format) link was suggested as a possible duplicate, but then the function in that answer accepts `Date` object. I want to convert string time to `Date`.

Comment: are you aware that JS !== Java????

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ im fairly new to JS

Comment: yeap... no problem... your question is related to js and not with java....

Comment: you are getting the attention of the wrong group of developers....

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different languages. Java solutions do not work in JavaScript. About point 2: You probably used the wrong name, because that JavaScript function is named `simpleDateFormat` and not `SimpleDateFormat` (note the difference, case is important).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you display javascript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format)

Comment: @Jesper still gives `simpleDateFormat is not defined`

Comment: @Hugo and for the answer in that question to work, wouldn't i need to send the date object to the function ?!

Comment: Did you actually include [the code from that page](https://github.com/noahcooper/SimpleDateFormatJS/blob/master/src/SimpleDateFormat.js) into your project? It's not a function that is available by default in JavaScript.

Comment: You can also split the string `01:00:00` and get the values you want, and build the output in a similar way. As you care only about the time, you don't need to create a date object.

Comment: @Hugo i thought of doing that, but then i also want to learn and understand how date time works in JS. Also then this isn't a duplicate question right ?!

Comment: I still think it's a duplicate, because it's **essentially** the same problem: how to format a time to am/pm format. If you also want to learn how date/time works in some language, that would be a too broad question for SO (in this case, you should search for books/tutorials/etc). If you [edit] the question adding your code attempts and explaining why it's different from another questions you've seen, maybe it won't be considered a duplicate (you just linked other questions but didn't explain what/how you've tried to solve your problem).

Comment: Case 1 doesn't work because `new Date` expects the full date in [some specific formats](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp). `simpleDateFormat` doesn't work because probably you're not including it in your project, or you're not calling it with lowercase `s` (`SimpleDateFormat` with uppercase `S` is a java class, not the javascript library). And for this specific problem, you don't need to create a date, you can just split the string, get the values for hour and minute, and use the code in the duplicate question in a similar way.

Comment: @Hugo Yaa... i think i'm left with no other options than to split it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , just use date object and extract hours and minutes , i think is easy to understand it

```
vvar str = "01:00:00"; var res = str.split(":"); 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[0]; // =01 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[1]; // =00 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[2]; // =00
```

so in your case , should be :

```
 var str = "01:00:00"; 
 var res = str.split(":");
 var hour = res[0]; // =01 
var minutes=res[1]; // = 00
var ampm = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
hour = hour % 12;
hour = hour ? hour : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
minutes = minutes < 10 ?  minutes : minutes;
var strTime = hour + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
alert(strTime);
```

ps. if u wanna use java , you can do it in a jsp page where you can use java , html and javascript .

Comment: this is same as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format) right ?! But then it would need a date object right ?!

Comment: yup  , "var date = new Date()" is alredy a date object , u dont have to call any libraries

Comment: But then how will i change `01:00:00` to the date object ?!

Comment: oh , didn't read that , well is easy to solve , just use "split" function like this:
`var str = "01:00:00";
    var res = str.split(":");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[0]; // =01
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[1]; // =00
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[2]; // =00
 `
so in your case , should be :
 `var str = "01:00:00";
    var res = str.split(":");
    var hour = res[0]; // =01
var minutes=res[1]; // = 00
 `

Comment: @gianquiroz You can [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45593357/edit) and add this code to it (much better and more readable than putting in the comments)

Comment: thank for the suggestion , i'm new in stackoverflow , i'm sorry u.u